# Google Analytics and cookies

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

My question is: I'm developing a website and I want to monitor analytics with Google Analytics, however I've been reading articles about cookies and I didn't realize if I need to program my website with some kind of cookies in order to use google tool, or if I simply don't need to do anything on my website.

Thanks

Comment: No, you don’t need to do anything else, only implement the code snippets Google gives you.

Answer (score 0):

To do tracking you simply need to insert the code snippet that you can get from the GA admin interface.

However since you are in the EU you need to point out to your visitors that they are being tracked on your web page and that the site uses cookies to do so (and I think you need to provide an opt-out, although that might be a German thing). This is mandated by the European Privacy directive, which is sometimes referred to as "Cookie Law" (technically incorrect, since it is neither a law nor specifically about cookies), so maybe this gave you the idea that you need to do extra programming.